Error using average_precision_score for multiclass in scikit-learn
I'm trying to compute the average precision score using the following code:
p = np.array([[.01,.05,.94],[.2,.6,.2],[.4,.35,.25]])
l = np.array([2,1,1])
aupr = average_precision_score(l, p, average="micro")

However, I get the following error:
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3, 3) instead.

The function works fine when I modify l to [2, 1, 0]. I assumed it would automatically detect the number of classes from the matrix p. What might I be misunderstanding here?
Thanks for your help!

Hello @ironv! Did my answer help you? If so, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer
